# How to find out memory layout of your data structure implementation on Linux 64bit machine

Tags: linux, data-structures, linux-kernel, ram, virtual-memory

In this article, http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/7/95061-youre-doing-it-wrong/fulltext

The author talks about the memory layouts of 2 data structures - The Binary Heap and the B-Heap and compares how one has better memory layout than the other (figures 5 and 6).

I want to get hands on experience on this. I have an implementation of a N-Ary Tree and I want to find out the memory layout of my data structure. What is the best way to come up with a memory layout like the one in the article?

Secondly, I think it is easier to identify the memory layout if it is an array based implementation. If the implementation of a Tree uses pointers then what Tools do we have or what kind of approach is required to map it's memory layout?

Comment: Interesting article! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Design a code for a **`data-structure`** to test

Pre-fill the **`data-structure`** under test with significant-values ( `0x00000000`, `0x01111111`, ... ) highlighting the layout borders & data belonging to `data-structure` elements

Use debugging tools to view actual live-memory content & layout that the coded **`data-structure`** element-under-test uses in-vivo

( be systematic & patient )

Comment: BTW: Nice referred paper -- love remarks on poor understanding & fatal misconcepts of quasi-optimisations, that have forgotten about real memory layouts and real access-pattern overheads ( **... since 1961, VM principles from ATLAS rule for some 53 years already** and more hands-on examples ) As per [mooray]'s approach -- would guess the <_favourite_scripting_language_> shall be in place for presentation, however **for true-test** the used compiler & linker (type/release/patch/hot-fix/settings) are defining the final mem-map-layout and associated allocation/access/processing overheads

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps just traversing the data structure to print element addresses (and sizes if they vary) would give you enough information to feed to for instance `graphviz`? I'm not sure why did you include the `linux-kernel` tag. Basic virtual memory mapping happens at page granularity (ignoring huge pages here) so physical vs virtual address don't matter. You can easily do your tests in user space.

I would proceed as follows:

1. place calls to dump your N-ary trees in the code OR use a GDB script to do it
2. write a script in your favourite scripting language to group objects into pages (masking lower 12 bits of addresses out gives page id), calculate statistics, see if objects span multiple pages, do whatever you want; output `graphviz` description file
3. run `graphviz` to enjoy the vizualisation

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is figure out the data you need to represent in graphical format.  The memory layout in Poul-Henning Kamp's figures are both the pointer structure, and contiguous virtual memory pages.  The former can easily be displayed using a debugging tool like [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd).  The latter takes a bit more effort, and there are more ways to accomplish it.

A few ideas...

- Write a function to traverse the data structure and print values, compile as scaffold code and run
- Add function and call it from a debugger, such as [gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/)
- Write a script to be called from a debugger

Another possibility nobody mentioned yet, would be reading through the specification for the language you're writing the code in.  This should generally let you determine the memory layout of the structures in the actual compiled code (C/C++, etc...), neglecting compiler optimization.  This can be altered by telling the compiler to lay out the data structures in non-default ways though (`alignas`, `__attribute__(aligned)`, etc...).  You would still need to consider how the memory is allocated from the heap and the operating system.

However, once you have the relevant values, you should be able to use any software you like to convert the data into a graphical format ([graphviz](http://graphviz.org/), etc...).